# Chrome extention with clickablelinks function

Tags: javascript

For work we often get log files with links in them, these are not provided with a <h ref tag and are therefore plain text in the log files. the purpose is that this script converts the links to a real h ref. so that you can click on it.

I'm trying to build a chrome extension, it already contains a popup with certain functions and it works.

I also want to build in a function that reads all websites and converts non-clickable links into clickable links.

I have part of the code but I can't get it to work...

background.js(problem with the id ):

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: id, allFrames: true},
    files: ["/content_scripts/clickablelinks.js"],
});;
```

clickablelinks.js:

```
// Make links clickable.
console.log("Script started");
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log("Tab updated: " + tabId);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      code: `
      console.log("Script executed");
        var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='http'], a[href^='https']");
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { 
          links[i].onclick = function() { 
            window.open(this.href); 
            return false; 
          }
        }
        $('body *').each(function() {
          var html = $(this).html();
          var newHtml = html.replace(/([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})/gi, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>');
          newHtml = newHtml.replace(/((https?|ftp):\/\/[^\s\/$.?#,\(\)].[^\s,]*)/gi, '<a href="$1">$1</a>');
          newHtml = newHtml.replace(/(((www.)?)([A-Z0-9])([^\s,]*)\.(eu|com|be|co\.uk|net|org|edu|gov|ca|de|fr|us|ru|ch|it|nl|se|no|es|ly|am)([^\s,\(\)]*))/gi, '<a href="http://$1">$1</a>');
          newHtml = newHtml.replace(/((?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))/gi, '<a href="http://$1">$1</a>');
          $(this).html(newHtml);
        });
        
      `
    });
    console.log("Script ended");
  });
```

manifest.json:

```
{
      "name": "Tech Tools",
      "content_scripts": [{
      "all_frames": true, 
      "matches": ["***private***"],
      "js": ["/js/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
  }],
      "description": "Easy shortcuts!",
      "version": "3.2.5",
      "manifest_version": 3,
      "background": {
      "service_worker": "/js/background.js"
  },
      "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "scripting", "background"],
      "host_permissions": [
      "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "/images/icon16.png",
      "32": "/images/icon32.png",
      "48": "/images/icon48.png",
      "128": "/images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/images/icon16.png",
    "32": "/images/icon32.png",
    "48": "/images/icon48.png",
    "128": "/images/icon128.png"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html"
  }
```

In hope for a bit help, kind regards...

some suggestions our a result...

Comment: What is a non-clickable link?

Comment: Hi Andy,
For work we often get log files with links in them, these are not provided with a <h ref tag and are therefore plain text in the log files. the purpose is that this script converts the links to a real h ref. so that you can click on it.